# Action Bar not visible in Android

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I am creating an Android app in Xamarin and want to display 3 Action Bar Tabs (Dashboard, Dialer & Reports). I am relatively new in android and below is my code. there is no error but even then the Action bar is not visible. The page is blank with just the Application Icon and Application name in it. I am using Jelly bean 4.0.3 emulator with API level 15. Please help as i am really stuck.

```
    namespace NIITDehradun
{
    [Activity (Label = "NIIT")]         
    public class mainniitActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            var actionBar = this.ActionBar;
            actionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

            var tab1 = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();
            tab1.SetText (Resource.String.tabdashname);
            tab1.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.dashboard);
            tab1.TabSelected+= (sender, e) => {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.fragment_container, new dashFragment ());
            };
            actionBar.AddTab (tab1);

            var tab2 = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();
            tab2.SetText (Resource.String.tabdialername);
            tab2.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.dialer);
            tab2.TabSelected+= (sender, e) => {

            };
            actionBar.AddTab (tab2);

            var tab3 = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();
            tab3.SetText (Resource.String.tabreportname);
            tab3.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.report);
            tab3.TabSelected+= (sender, e) => {

            };
            actionBar.AddTab (tab3);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.mainniit);


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: you can't say that there is no error if the action bar does not display correctly, right?

Answer (score 0):

you  can try:

```
actionBar.show();
```

try to replace `var actionBar = this.ActionBar`; by `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar()`; and then add an actionBarlistener. this is an example : [Action bar with tab](http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example)

Comment: I tried actionBar.show(); but the result is the same there is no display of action bar.

Comment: try to change this.ActionBar by getActionBar()